# What is meant by In-Place Matrix Inversion?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I come across the term "In Place Matrix Inversion" a lot in numerical libraries like NumPy and ND4J. What does it mean ? How is it different from the normal matrix inversion ? What are the advantages and disadvantages of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the memory that was used to store the matrix is now used to store the inverted matrix.  The advantages is that is saves memory and may be faster to calculate.

The disadvantage is is breaks referential transparency.

Also if you wish to use the uninverted matrix after you did the inversion you can't because it no longer exists.

Comment: @Q the Platypus: Could you please explain in a bit more detail what you mean that we might be dealing with the matrix and its inverse at the same time.

Comment: Hope t he edit clarifies.

Comment: @Q the Platypus yes it does.

Comment: @Machina333 : the Gauss pivot algorithm requires a copy of the matrix, so it might mean that no more space allocation is needed (or that it is small compared to the matrix size). the space complexity of the algorithm becomes very important in the case of a sparse $N \times N$ matrix when $N > 2^{16}$ since you can't safely compute the inverse if it is not sparse (more than 4GB of necessary space)